# calculus find the equation of the line

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of the line through the point (2,5) that cuts off the least area from the first quadrant. Give your answer using the form below.
y-A=B(x-C)
A=?, B=?, C=?

Anyone can explain this problem?

Comment: Wow.. what an awfully posed problem.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of any line passing through $(2,5)$ can be written as $\displaystyle \frac{y-5}{x-2}=m$ where $m$ is the gradient

$$\implies y-5=mx-2m\iff mx-y=2m-5\iff \frac x{\frac{2m-5}m}+\frac y{-(2m-5)}=1$$

$$\implies\triangle=\frac12\left|\frac{2m-5}m\cdot(5-2m)\right|=\frac{(2m-5)^2}{2|m|} $$

$$\text{Use } |m|=\begin{cases} +m &\mbox{if } m\ge0 \\
-m & \mbox{if } m<0. \end{cases} $$ and then  [Second derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test)